# Long time Oracle developer/DBA learning SQL Server - book recommendations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I've been developing and administering Oracle database apps for many years, and would like to learn SQL Server. Does anyone have any book recommendations (preferably electronic). Naturally enough I already know SQL inside/out so I'd like to avoid any intro stuff and go straight to the meat, but not skip any basic SQL Server things I'd learn from an intro book. Any suggestions?

tia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely recommend:

- [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243): goes deep but does not neglect the fundamentals. ***It is a must read*.**
- [Professional SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484284): similar to the first book, but with a slightly more performance based focus.
- [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219025): great techniques for identifying and fixing poorly performing queries, from the metal to the application.
- [SQL Server MVP Deep Dives](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182048): written by some of the world's leading SQL Server experts and practitioners. [There's a short review [here](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2010/02/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives-book-review.html). Volume 2 is due out somewhere around November 2011, I believe]

If you have more of a development focus:

- [Pro SQL Server 2008 Relational Database Design and Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143020866X)
- [Expert SQL Server 2005 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059729X) (SQL Server 2005 but still relevant for SQL Server 2008)

There are also some very good, free electronic books from [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/):

- [Inside the SQL Server Query Optimizer](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/inside-sql-server-query-optimizer)
- [Performance Tuning with SQL Server Dynamic Management Views](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/dynamic-management-views)
- [Brad's Sure Guide to SQL Server Maintenance Plans](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/sql-server-maintenance-plans)
- [SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/sql-server-execution-plans)

to list a few.

Comment: +1 The Grant Fitchley "SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled" book is the best technical book I've ever read